# Where to find good looking and Vista look-alike user interface icons?

Tags: windows, user-interface, icons, windows-vista, look-and-feel

Ok, I know that Visual Studio ships with a few user interface icons but they are few and most of all, they are kinda outdated and don't fit well into Vista or Seven.

I like pretty interfaces and I like interfaces where they fit and look part of the OS. One of the problems regarding this is the interface icons, I can't find good icons in 16x16 (for menus and toolbars) that work nicely with recent Windows versions.

Looking for free stuff mostly but would like to know of commercial (but not very expensive) alternatives.

Does anyone know of any good icons that could fit well into Vista/Seven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a big fan of the icons available here:  http://www.iconfinder.net

They seem to be fairly up-to-date looking, and have a pretty decent set to choose from.

Most of the icons are licensed under GPL.

Answer (score 3):

I like the [silk icons](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/)
They are under the [Creative Commons License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/) - free to use and distribute.

Comment: The silk icons are awesome, there are also a few extension sets around that match the style and use the same base elements.

Comment: @Simon: Any links to the extensions? Because I sorely miss a "funnel"-icon in the set.

Answer (score 2):

This is the mother of all icon collection directories:

http://www.freeiconsdownload.com/

I'm sure you'll find something that fits your needs.

This one may also be of interest:

http://www.dezinerfolio.com/2007/09/25/top-50-supercool-free-icon-sets/

Answer (score 0):

The main limitation that is the size of the icons you need - 16x16 isn't a lot of space to give a "wizz bang" effect that the new OSes strive for.  In this age of more screen real-estate with bigger resolutions (and somtimes even DPI), the icon have been growing likewise.  To keep with the same look and feel of Vista and Windows 7, you may consider increasing the icon size.

If you need smaller icons - the silk set mentioned already is great.  Here is a good list of some more smaller icon sets:

[Collection of Small Icons for Web Development](http://www.metatitan.com/design/11/collection-of-small-icons-for-web-development.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another great icon set that I just came across (via [Google Blogoscoped](http://blogoscoped.com/)).

http://www.fatcow.com/free-icons/index.bml

Not sure how "Vista-like" they are.  They're more along the lines of the Silk icon set from FamFamFam.  Good thing is that they offer a 32x32 version as well as the 16x16.

They're all Creative Commons.